# Android: Error at passing a Parcelable object to another Activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I'm trying to pass one object from my MainActivity to another. It has an atribute of the type ArrayList which is changed and I don't know why. In the MainActivity I use object's `toString` and `System.out.println()` to see what he has and I can see this:

```
Incidente{name='Farola fundida', type='sin luz', street='falsa', streetNumber=123, city='Bilbao', contacts=[alguien1, alguien2]}
```

However, when I receive it on the other activity I make another `System.out.println()` and I get this:

```
Incidente{name='Farola fundida', type='sin luz', street='falsa', streetNumber=123, city='Bilbao', contacts=[, null]}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My class `Incidente` code is this:

```
public class Incidente implements Parcelable{

    String name;
    String type;
    String street;
    int streetNumber;
    String city;
    ArrayList<String> contacts;

    public Incidente(String name, String type, String street, int streetNumber, String city, ArrayList<String> contacts) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.street = street;
        this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
        this.city = city;
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }


    protected Incidente(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        type = in.readString();
        street = in.readString();
        streetNumber = in.readInt();
        city = in.readString();
        contacts = in.createStringArrayList();
    }

    public static final Creator<Incidente> CREATOR = new Creator<Incidente>() {
        @Override
        public Incidente createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Incidente(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Incidente[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Incidente[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(type);
        dest.writeString(street);
        dest.writeInt(streetNumber);
        dest.writeString(city);
        dest.writeList(contacts);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public int getStreetNumber() {
        return streetNumber;
    }

    public void setStreetNumber(int streetNumber) {
        this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    public void setContacts(ArrayList<String> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Incidente{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", street='" + street + '\'' +
                ", streetNumber=" + streetNumber +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", contacts=" + contacts +
                '}';
    }

    public boolean equals (Incidente obj2)
    {

        if(this.getName().equals(obj2.getName()))
        {
            if(this.getType().equals(obj2.getType()))
            {
                if(this.getStreet().equals(obj2.getStreet()))
                {
                    if(this.getStreetNumber()== obj2.getStreetNumber())
                    {
                        if(this.getCity().equals(obj2.getStreetNumber()))
                        {
                            if(this.getContacts().equals(obj2.getContacts()))
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is how I send the object:

```
ArrayList<String> arrContactos=new ArrayList<String>();
arrContactos.add("alguien1");
arrContactos.add("alguien2");
Incidente inci = new Incidente("Farola fundida", "sin luz", "falsa", 123, "Bilbao", arrContactos);

Intent i = new Intent(this, DetalleIncidenteActivity.class);
i.putExtra("objeto",inci);
```

And this is how I receive it:

```
incidente=getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("objeto");
```

Comment: Not related to the error. But read this for overriding equals..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [createStringArrayList](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Parcel.html):

> Read and return a new ArrayList containing String objects from the
> parcel that was written with writeStringList(List) at the current
> dataPosition().

So, accordingly to the documentation you should be using `writeStringList(List)` instead of `writeList`

Answer (score 0):

Generated using [parcelabler](http://www.parcelabler.com/)

```
public class Incidente implements Parcelable, Parcelable {

        String name;
        String type;
        String street;
        int streetNumber;
        String city;
        ArrayList<String> contacts;

        protected Incidente(Parcel in) {
            name = in.readString();
            type = in.readString();
            street = in.readString();
            streetNumber = in.readInt();
            city = in.readString();
            if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
                contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
                in.readList(contacts, String.class.getClassLoader());
            } else {
                contacts = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeString(type);
            dest.writeString(street);
            dest.writeInt(streetNumber);
            dest.writeString(city);
            if (contacts == null) {
                dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
            } else {
                dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
                dest.writeList(contacts);
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<Incidente> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Incidente>() {
            @Override
            public Incidente createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Incidente(in);
            }

            @Override
            public Incidente[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Incidente[size];
            }
        };
    }
```